# PERL substr: using variable for subsitution

Tags: perl

I'm trying to pass a variable to substr
so that each time 'work' will be substituted 
with an incremented number

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $find = "work";
my $string = "why doesnt this work?";
my $idx;

for(my $replace = 0; $replace < 3;  $replace++) {
   if( ($idx= index($string, $find)) > -1 ) {
      substr($string, $idx, 4, $replace);
   }
   print "[#$replace] $string\n";
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[#0] why doesnt this 0?
[#1] why doesnt this 0?
[#2] why doesnt this 0?
```

How can a variable be used in substr ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After your first call of `substr()` on `$string`, these is no 'work' in this string, try this:

```
my $find = "work";
my $org_string = "why doesnt this work?";
my $idx;

for(my $replace = 0; $replace < 3;  $replace++) {
    my $string = $org_string;
   if( ($idx= index($string, $find)) > -1 ) {
      substr($string, $idx, 4, $replace);
   }
   print "[#$replace] $string\n";
}
```